# Can SQL be affected by a comment?

Tags: java, ibatis

There is a comment on my sql xml, the result from **ibatis** is incorrect, but when I execute the sql on DB directly the result is correct.

And if I remove the comment, the result is also correct. I guess the comment caused this problem. who can tell me the reason ?

```
AND a.oprnt_ymdt < SYSDATETIME - (1000 * 60) * 10 /* DATE_SUB(SYSDATETIME, INTERVAL #searchTerm# MINUTE) */
```

Comment: Which database engine is it? SQL Server? MySQL? PostgreSQL? One of the many, many others? Have you tried to use the `--` comment or a `//` instead of the block comment? What makes the output incorrect? Can you show desired and actual output?

Comment: check your database record sample for your both conditions manually first.

Comment: @deHaar Thanks for your reply. I am sorry , because i can't show more code . It's MySQL.  if i replace the comment with ```/* aaaaaa */```, the result is correct.  but ```/* DATE_SUB(SYSDATETIME, INTERVAL #searchTerm# MINUTE) */``` will not right...

Answer (score 0):

you must remove #searchTerm# from your comment (more specifily, you must remove any #...# code) because the ibatis template engine ignores the java style comments (only xml comments are allowed) and add a new parameter to the prepared statement generated.